# Module inside an object

Tags: ocaml

I would like to define a parameterized module inside an object by the type of this object.

I have two module interlocked :

```
(* Parameters*)
module type A = sig
        type agent
        type intern_agent = { i : agent}
        val create : agent -> intern_agent
end

module type E = sig
        type event
end



module  type StateType = sig

  type agent
  type event

  type  state_t = { 
    mutable name : string;
    mutable parentstate  :  state_t option;
  }
end


module State (A : A) (E : E) = struct

        type agent = A.agent
        type event = E.event
    type  state_t = { 
            mutable name : string;
             mutable parentstate  :  state_t option;
    }


    (*...*)
end


module Agent (S : StateType) =
        struct
          type agent = S.agent
          type event = S.event
          type state_t = S.state_t

      type  agent_t = {
          mutable agent      : agent ;
      }

      let create a1   = {
          agent          = a1;
      }
end

(* An implementation of E*)
type event1 = Event1 | Event2;;
module E = struct type event = event1 end;;
```

What I would like to do is something like that (which is syntacticly incorrect but represents what I would like to do) :

```
class  character = object (self :'self)
 val mutable position        = (0,0)
 val agent                         =
                let A = (module Ag  = struct
                                type agent = 'self
                                type intern_agent = { i : agent}
                                let create a = { i = a }
                              end)
                     in
                let Ag = (module Agent(State(A)(E)) ) in
                Ag.create self

 method getPosition          = position

end;;
```

How can I write this to be able to define a value which is an Agent parametrized by itself ?

Thank you

Comment: One solution I got is to avoid to define the module by the Agent.

Answer (score 0):

Syntactically correct version of a character class definition is

```
class  character = object (self :'self)
  val mutable position        = (0,0)
  val agent =
    let module A = struct
      type agent = character
      type intern_agent = { i : agent}
      let create a = { i = a }
    end in
    let module Ag = Agent(State(A)(E)) in
    Ag.create self

  method getPosition          = position
end
```

Although, it wont compile, since agent_t will escape the scope of the value agent definition. Indeed, you're asking a compiler to allow you to return a value from a function that has type local to the function.

I wish I can give you some advice on how to redesign your code, but I need more information about your intentions.